# Как убрать отступы с черточками при выводе на печать в консоле текста

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup, bs4

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get("https://nasoscentr.ru/catalog/nasosy-tipa-d-1d-2d/")
web_page = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page, "html.parser")
article_price = soup.find(name="div", class_="price font-bold font_mxs").getText()

print(article_price)
```

В консоли печатается с большим отступом, вот так:

```
------------------------------------Цена: по запросу------------------------------------
```

Т.е. по слева и с права от надписи "Цена: по запросу" печатаются отступы в виде черточек. Не могу понять, почему печатается отступы и черточки с двух сторон. Как сделать так, чтобы выводился текс без отступов, т.е. надпись "Цена: по запросу" была прижата к левому краю?

Answer (score 1):

Это убрало пробелы - `.strip()`

Т.е. решение такое: `print(article_price.strip())`